# Symfony/Codeception Run Errors

Tags: symfony, codeception

I have a Symfony 2.4.4 site with simple Codeception (2.1.7) acceptance tests setup. When running the acceptance tests I get the following error:

```
[Codeception\Exception\ConfigurationException]
AcceptanceTester class doesn't exist in suite folder.
Run the 'build' command to generate it
```

The `AcceptanceTester` class does exist in the `tests/acceptance` directory. If I run a build I get the following error:

```
[Codeception\Exception\ConfigurationException]
Configuration file could not be found.
Run `bootstrap` to initialize Codeception.
```

The `codeception.yml` file does exist and contains the following:

```
actor: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    helpers: tests/_support
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    colors: false
    memory_limit: 1024M
coverage:
    enabled: true
    remote: true
    include:
        - app/*
    exclude:
        - app/cache/*
include:
    ...
modules:
    config:
        Db:
            dsn: ''
            user: ''
            password: ''
            dump: tests/_data/dump.sql
```

If I run a bootstrap it confirms this:

```
Project is already initialized in '.'
```

acceptance.suite.yml contains:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - AcceptanceHelper
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

1. AcceptanceTester.php file should be in tests/_support directory.
   Run `codecept build` to regenerate Tester files.
2. You have no modules enabled acceptance.suite.yml.
   You have to enable one of Symfony2, PhpBrowser and WebDriver.
3. Your site uses an old version of Symfony and it can cause issues for Codeception if Symfony2 module is used, so I recommend to test it using PhpBrowser or WebDriver.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on AcceptanceTester.php. As above however, the `codecept build` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you need to run command `codecept bootstrap`.

Comment: As stated above, if I run bootstrap it throws an error:
`Project is already initialized in '.'`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and I realise that I ran the `codecept bootstrap` but the `vendor` and the `tests` folders were in a wrong directory.

I followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B3PE7w-jvjQ) and it helped me.

Comment: Please use comments to link external resources, otherwise provide a complete answer with code and explanation.